# agora issue in hide message from teacher on live meeting

Tags: agora.io, agora-web-sdk-ng

anyone can help me in issue for  ??
how can i hide popup or any messages coming while demo with teacher in recording from attendee
2.  Oops the  user is disconnected and student disconnect from meeting suddenly

Answer (score 0):

You can use `NotificationListenerService` to disable all the notification while your app is in the foreground. You can read more about it [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/service/notification/NotificationListenerService)

This code might help you out

```kotlin
public class NotificationListener extends NotificationListenerService {

    @Override
    public void onNotificationPosted(StatusBarNotification statusBarNotification) {
      cancelAllNotifications(); 
    }
}
```

Also, don't forget to add this to your AndroidManifest

```xml
 <service android:name=".NotificationListener"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:permission="android.permission.BIND_NOTIFICATION_LISTENER_SERVICE">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.service.notification.NotificationListenerService" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
```